# jumbotron height and float

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

im kind of new to css/html and bootstrap itself. I've encountered two problems.

One is: I want to fix the 3rd and 4th box height to 100%, but no mater what div, or class i change to 100% it makes no changes.

Second: How can i make Box4 go under box2, so its not inline with box3?

Link to describe problem: http://jsfiddle.net/BXZrX/6/

and here is a picture of what i want: http://oi62.tinypic.com/osqule.jpg

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1>Join now!</h1>
            <p>To get full use of the website, register now!.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Sign up</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bordertop">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h1>Box2</h1>
                <p>text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box3">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h1>Box3</h1>
                <p>text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box4">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h1>Box4</h1>
                <p>text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
       </div>
#content > div {
float:left;
width:49%;
}
#content > div.bordertop {
    float:right;
    width:49%;
}
#content > div.box3 {
    clear:both;
    width:49%;
    float:left;
}
#content > div.box4 {
    float:right;
    width:49%;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you want the page to look like?

Comment: something like this: http://oi62.tinypic.com/osqule.jpg i updated the jsfiddle also

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start:
http://jsfiddle.net/jPZLd/11/

I've swapped boxes 2 and 3 so that they flow correctly down then across the page:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h1>Join now!</h1>
                <p>To get full use of the website, register now!.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Sign up</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bordertop">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <h1>Box2</h1>
                    <p>text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <div class="box3">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <h1>Box3</h1>
                    <p>text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box4">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <h1>Box4</h1>
                    <p>text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    Footer

        </div>
```

If you need both boxes 2 and 4 to have the same baseline, it's easy if your content is static - just adjust the height of the shorter box manually, eg.

```
.box4 .jumbotron {
    height: 319px;
}
```

It gets a bit harder if you have to deal with dynamic content. I think you'd end up needing to fake it by applying the background color to the container element and hiding the bits you don't want to see.

Comment: Working good thanks! Now i only need the bottom boxes to stretch to the footer. 

I read the bootstrap documentation but i couldn't find anything about the span class, do you have any more information about that?

Comment: Oops - the span classes aren't supported in the latest version of bootstrap. Your original CSS was doing all of the work. I've renamed them to 'column'.

Comment: #content > div {
float:left;
width:49%;
}
The above CSS was actually doing all the work. I just added the 'column' divs to make it work as you intended.

Remember to vote up answers you find helpful :)

Comment: I've updated my post with some details about getting the boxes' baselines to line up.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers! very helpful. The one thing im wondering about is why height:100%; doesn't work for the jumbotron.